# Cómo quitar los estilos por defecto de tailwinds css para un segmento en especifico

Tags: css, next.js, tailwind, tinymce

Estoy usando taildwinds css en next:13, y con un editor de rich text (TinyMCE) en el cual estoy generando la descripción de un producto que incluyen diferentes elementos como listas y tablas. Esto se almacena en una base de datos.

En el editor los estilos están bien, pero cuando coloco **product.description** dentro de una etiqueta me aplica los estilos por defecto de tailwinds.

###### En tiny MCE:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para este segmento en especifico, ¿Cómo desactivo los estilos por defecto de tailwinds sin afectar al proyecto entero?

```
import parse from "html-react-parser";

...

{/* DESCRIPCION */}
<div className="w-full h-[350px] overflow-auto bg-gray-100 rounded-md p-4 mt-4 scrollbar-thin scrollbar-thumb-gray-400 scrollbar-thumb-rounded-full scrollbar-track-gray-200">
  <div className="list-disc">
    {parse(product?.description || "")}
  </div>
</div>
```

---

###### Resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

puedes usar la clase de CSS [all](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/all). Directamente al div que contiene tu descripción:

```
<div style={{ all: 'initial' }} className="list-disc">
    {parse(product?.description || "")}
</div>
```